# Cannot use React Native CLI to initialize project with version lower than 0.60.0

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use react-native init ABC --version 0.57.0 and it has an error. Tried to use other formats of init, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If anybody needs to install 0.59.x do this:

```sh
mkdir rn59cli
cd rn59cli
npm init -f
npm install react-native-cli
node_modules/.bin/react-native init Rn59SampleApp --version 0.59.10
```

```sh
Using yarn v1.21.1
Installing react-native@0.59.10...
yarn add v1.21.1
warning ../../package.json: No license field
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
info Direct dependencies
└─ react-native@0.59.10
```

```js
$ cat Rn59SampleApp/package.json
{
  "name": "Rn59SampleApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: upvoted! is this really the only way to create a 0.59.X react-native project? I've been trying all sorts of options.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing react-native CLI

Comment: Still the same error. My npm version is greater than 5. Thanks for your reply

Comment: try reinstalling react-native CLI

Comment: I have edited my previous answer so you can accept it as answer